# Web scraping in Node.js

Tags: javascript, node.js, http, heroku, web-scraping

Lately I've been trying to scrape Information from a website using Nodejs, the request module and cheerio. The code it works well (**statusCode = 200**) on my localhost (127.0.0.1) but when I push the code to Heroku server, **statusCode = 403**.

Is it because of the cookie? If yes, why does it work on my localhost that doesn't add any cookie in the request?

```
request({
    method: 'GET',
    headers: {
        'user-agent': 'Mozilla/5.0 (Windows NT 10.0; Win64; x64) AppleWebKit/537.36 (KHTML, like Gecko) Chrome/70.0.3538.77 Safari/537.36'
    }, 
    url: 'https://www.example.com/login',
    json: true
}, (err, response, body) => {
    if (err) {
        return console.log('Failed to request: ', err);
    }
    console.log(response.statusCode);
```

});

Comment: Check the permissions on the server

Comment: You're not literally trying to hit `https://www.example.com/login`, are you? That domain is reserved for documentation. We have no way of knowing if this is cookie related (or anything else) without a real domain, or more information. Please read [ask].

Comment: Also, you should check your server logs for more information. On Heroku you can do this by running `heroku logs`.